# Check if a word in a string is longer than 50 characters

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

There are other posts I know, but they aren't about java.
What I'm asking for is a way to check if a string contains a word that is longer than 56 characters. I want then to insert a " " inside the word(probably in the middle). I want the spaces in the original string to remain there.(split(" ") doesn't help me because of that).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Pattern.compile("\\w{56,}").matcher(string).find()
```

assuming, of course, your definition of "word" matches Pattern's definition of "word character": `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`

To unpack, that just looks for 56 or more consecutive word characters.

If you liked, you could even hold on to the `Matcher` object, which would let you get the `start()` and `end()` of the 56+ letter word.

Comment: This is great, but how do I insert a " " in the middle when I find the word?

Comment: If you hold onto the `Matcher` object, you can get the position of the word, and then do whatever you like with that.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the string, using the `indexOf()` method to find the next space.  Compare the current index against the previous one to see if it exceeds 50.  Insert your space at the midpoint, and restart your indexOf() loop from that point.